# Android Button onPress Color

Tags: android

I know this has been asked a nos of times but i am not able to change the button background color when pressed. Here are the codes. When the page is launched the button bg color is black but when i press it, it changes to green - probably it might be at code level which i have no access so i want to use the xml file configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@android:color/black"/>
<item android:state_enabled="true"
    android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/black" />
<item android:state_enabled="true"
    android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@android:color/black" />
<item android:state_enabled="true"
    android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/black" />
</selector>
```

and

```
  <Button
                            android:id="@+id/payBtn"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@drawable/button_background_selector"
                            android:onClick="onPayPressed"
                            android:text="@string/pf_pay_btn_hint"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textColorLink="@android:color/white"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/pf_20_txt_size" />
```

Comment: what is expected behavior of button color.

Comment: default color to be black and on press the color should be black only.

Comment: It looks like in provided code, there is no green color mentioned in xml,
 Please check your activity/fragment code, if you have used any background color added :- especially `green` color AND default selector state should be at the end only (you have added it at very first)

Answer (score 0):

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.loginbtn)    
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#555555"));
```